# Posting multiple model Objects with Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to pass multiple model objects using AJAX:
Jquery Code:

```
function UpdateTestSpec(deviceType, dataSet, lineNumber, orderNumber) {
    var dataModel = {
        inputs: {
            SearchInputs: { DeviceType: deviceType, DatasetKey: dataSet, LineNumber: lineNumber, OrderNo: orderNumber }
        },
            serverName: sessionStorage.getItem("selectedServer")
};
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'TestSpecSearchResult',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: dataModel,
        dataType: "HTML",
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#testSpecTable").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult TestSpecSearchResult(TestSpecModels inputs, string serverName,int? page)
    {
    }
```

Models:

```
public class TestSpecModels
{
    public TestSpecModels()
    {
        CurrencyTestSpecChannel = new CurrencyTestSpecChannel();
        CurrencyTestSpecs = new CurrencyTestSpecs();
        SearchInputs = new TestSpecSearchInputs();
        CreateTestSpecs = new TestSpec();
    }
    public CurrencyTestSpecChannel CurrencyTestSpecChannel { get; set; }
    public CurrencyTestSpecs CurrencyTestSpecs { get; set; }
    public TestSpecSearchInputs SearchInputs { get; set; }
    public TestSpec CreateTestSpecs { get; set; }

}

public class TestSpecSearchInputs
{
    public Devices? DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string DatasetKey { get; set; }
    public int? LineNumber { get; set; }
    public int? OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
   

}
```

I have tried to create dataModel which will contains the inputs as expected in the action and within the inputs I have added the second model that will contains all data needed but what I am getting is null for the SearchInputs values. So how can I send data to the controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `POST` instead of `GET`if you want to pass complex data to your controller.

When you use `GET` it only concatenate the parameter to its url query string and if it is an object inside an object it became an array of object which your parameter can't understand.

If you used `POST` it will pass the complex data correctly to a value that the parameter in your controller can understand.

Comment: Okay but in my case I would like to display data and get data how would that be done.

Comment: You can still use `POST`. And in your post controller just get the data and return the model you need in your view. `GET` and `POST` is a way of transferring data from client to the server. It's not because you need to get data doesn't mean you can only use `GET`.